# Change CSS :before from PHP with multiple occurences

Tags: php, html, css

If in PHP, a program outputs a `<div>`, which has a `:before` part to it, which my code should choose the attributes for. As my code has multiple instances where the `:before` should have different attributes, I cannot just edit the `.css` file or create a `<style>` tag at the top.

I have tried to create a new `<style>` tag before each `<div>`, but all the attributes end up being the same last `<style>` (Yes, I know why). So my current thinking is to be able to edit the `:before` from within the `<div style="">` but I can't seem to be able to get `:before` to be changed there.

Does anyone know how to either edit the `:before` part within the tag's `style = ""` if that is even possible or another solution to this?

My current hypothesis *(which didn't work for the fact that the first letter in CSS stands for Cascading)* :

```
$array = [["text" => "Example 1", "colour" => "#880000"],["text" => "Example 2", "colour" => "#008800"]
foreach($array as $current){
    echo '<style>
        div.before{
            color: '.$current["colour"].';
        }
        </style>';
    echo '<div><p>'.$current["text"].'</p></div>'
}
```

(Note: In the actual code it is coming from a database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP to determine styling I would strongly advise creating a custom stylesheet that you conditionally control.

HTML

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/custom_style.php' />
```

CSS

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

    $brandColor = "#990000";
    $linkColor = "#555555";
    $CDNURL = "http://cdn.blahblah.net";

    #header {
        background: url("<?php echo $CDNURL; ?>/images/header-bg.png") no-repeat;
    }
    a {
       color: <?php echo $linkColor; ?>;
    }

    ul#main-nav li a {
       color: <?php echo $linkColor; ?>;
    }
?>
```

Example Source http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/

Based on your code I would assign a class to the div depending on the color. You will need to replace the `#` with a letter for CSS to read it.

```
$array = [["text" => "Example 1", "colour" => "#880000"],["text" => "Example 2", "colour" => "#008800"]

foreach($array as $current){
    $className = str_replace('#', 'C', $current["colour"]);
    echo '<style>';
    echo 'div.'.$className.':before {
            color: '.$current["colour"].';
        }';
    echo '</style>';
    echo '<div class="'.$className.'"><p>'.$current["text"].'</p></div>'
}
```